# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'dist2' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this functions that should return me the distance from point p to segment line v-w.
The problem i have is after some time i receive the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'dist2' of object [object Object] is not a function.

I receive it in distToSegmentSquared directly,not even calling the function dist2().Is it any other dist2() anywhere in jquery?I found none.

Code:

```
function sqr(x) {
    return x * x;
}

function dist2(v, w) {
    console.log(v);
    console.log(w);
    return sqr(v.x - w.x) + sqr(v.y - w.y);
}

function distToSegmentSquared(p, v, w) {
    var l2 = dist2(v, w);
    if (l2 == 0)
        return dist2(p, v);
    var t = ((p.x - v.x) * (w.x - v.x) + (p.y - v.y) * (w.y - v.y)) / l2;
    if (t < 0)
        return dist2(p, v);
    if (t > 1)
        return dist2(p, w);
    return dist2(p, {x: v.x + t * (w.x - v.x),
        y: v.y + t * (w.y - v.y)});
}

function distToSegment(p, v, w) {
    return Math.sqrt(distToSegmentSquared(p, v, w));
}
```

The values that are given in for that error are:

```
p: Object
x: 461
y: 333

v: Object
x: 80
y: 120

w: Object
x: 260
y: 120
```

Comment: What line exactly, did you trace the callstack?

Comment: var l2 = dist2(v, w);

died here

Comment: Could you reproduce this on jsfiddle? That error doesn't seem to make sense in your code, you're not calling `dist2` on any object as far as I can see.

Comment: i don't think i really can....it's a pretty big code,i could try to offer you a link and explain what to do to crash it if i'm allowed to?!.

Comment: Try the jsfiddle, remove what's not important and try to reproduce the problem otherwise it is very hard to tell what the issue is. I would look for `.dist2` in your editor and see if you find any culprits. That piece of code you posted doesn't seem to match that error.

Comment: ok,i fixed it...i renamed it to dist22() and everything works like a charms...wtf;

also,worked on chrome , guess it's because of it and its functions

Comment: That suggests a more serious problem then... Try putting a breakpoint where you think the problem is in Chrome devtools, then trace the error from there, other than that I can't tell what the source of the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your error is emanating from the fact that JavaScript does not have a **sqr** function.  I put in one

```
function sqr(v){return Math.pow(v,2);}
```

and wrote this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQKkM/).  Everything is hunkry-dory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in jsfiddle,I can't find any error: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwheM/).

```
 var result=distToSegment(
            {x:10,y:2}, {x:5,y:2}, {x:9,y:10}
            );
```